# android lib upload on bintray

Tags: bintray, jcenter

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':mylib:bintrayUpload'.

  > Could not create package 'username/maven/mylib': HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found [message:Repo 'maven' was not found]

Comment: Please provide more information on what you are trying to do, code, or links

Comment: The error message states that your repository maven isn't found. Do you have such repository? check the `https://bintray.com/username/maven`

Comment: You can check the user manual for more info, https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/uploads/uploads_uploads.html#_how_to_upload